# Adonsjs 4 - what is use() and why it not work in version 5

Tags: adonis.js

I try to understand the code https://github.com/nuxt-community/adonuxt-template .
What is use() and why it not work in version 5.
How to change?

```
const { Ignitor } = require('@adonisjs/ignitor')

new Ignitor(require('@adonisjs/fold'))
  .appRoot(__dirname)
  .fireHttpServer()
  .then(() => {
    return use('App/Services/Nuxt').build()
  })
  .then(() => {
    use('Logger').info('Nuxt is ready to handle requests')
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

And how to rewrite that files to work in version 5:

https://github.com/nuxt-community/adonuxt-template/blob/master/start/app.js
https://github.com/nuxt-community/adonuxt-template/blob/master/app/Commands/NuxtBuild.js
https://github.com/nuxt-community/adonuxt-template/blob/master/app/Controllers/Http/NuxtController.js
https://github.com/nuxt-community/adonuxt-template/blob/master/app/Services/Nuxt.js

Answer (score 3):

The `use()` method which was used to import dependencies from ioc container aka adonis-fold has been removed in v5. The alternative to that method is now ESM imports which uses `@ioc` prefix. Kindly follow this introductory guide https://docs.adonisjs.com/releases/introducing-adonisjs-v5-preview#esm-imports-all-the-way.

AdonisJS v5 has various breaking changes with regards to v4, also there are major changes in dev tools as well such as typescript as the first-class citizen, adonis cli is deprecated. Also AdonisJS team is expected to release upgrade guide in near future.

Answer (score 2):

use () is provided by the IoC container AdonisJs (adonis-fold).

This function will try to resolve the binding or namespace defined in the Adonis config file and then fall back to the default require() function to import the package if it doesn't find anything.